# Sending url parameters through file_get_contents returns nothig

Tags: php

I am trying to scrape a website in order to get latitude and longitude for counties in the us(there are 3306 thus why I am trying to do it through code and not manually)

I am using the code below

```php
function GetLatitude($countyName,$stateShortName){
        //Create DOM from url
        $page = file_get_contents("https://www.mapdevelopers.com/geocode_tool.php?$countyName,$stateShortName");
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($page);
        $node = $doc->getElementById("display_lat");

        var_dump($doc);
    }

    GetLatitude("Guilford County","NC");
```

This returns nothing but if I change the url to get without the parameters like "https://www.mapdevelopers.com/geocode_tool.php" then I can see that `$doc` now has some information in it but that is not useful because the value I need (latitude) is dependent upon the parameters passed into the url.

How do I solve this issue?

EDIT:

Based on the suggestion to encode the parameters I changed my code to this and now the document contains information but appears as though it is ignoring the parameters

```php
<?
function GetLatitude($countyName,$stateShortName){
    $countyName = urlencode($countyName);
    $stateShortName = urlencode($stateShortName);
    //Create DOM from url
    $page = file_get_contents("https://www.mapdevelopers.com/geocode_tool.php?address=$countyName,$stateShortName");
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($page);
    $node = $doc->getElementById("display_lat");

    var_dump($doc);
    }

    GetLatitude("Clarke County","AL");
?>
```

Comment: Did you mean `$countyName` instead of `countyName`? Also, you have to [encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the parameters.

Comment: yea lol typed the answer in a rush

Comment: maybe you need to urlencode the county name first? Might be that it expects `Guilford%20County` not `Guilford County`

Comment: @zack6849 I have updated my question to reflect my changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching the page there is a ajax request to `https://www.mapdevelopers.com/data.php`
Sending a POST or GET request will give you the response you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the latitude information etc isn't present on page load, and java script puts it there

You're going to have a hard time trying to run a webpage with JS and scraping it from PHP without something in the middle, maybe re-try this project with something like puppet or phantomjs so you can run your script against a real browser.

Comment: Is there not a way to tell php to make sure the page is fully loaded first

Comment: due to the fact that this will be used inside of another script that will be updating our database there is no way around using  php

Comment: PHP Can't run javascript, you could write a shell script called from php that calls something else I listed above to get the list and return them that way, but that's very duct-tape ad bubblegum-y